# Checking Workspace while installing

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i was installing ros melodic following this link
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment  i typed this command to check my workspcae

echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

and i got this

/opt/ros/melodic/share

instead of

/home/youruser/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share

can i continue without any problem or do i have any. pls help this is my first time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339639/checking-workspace-while-installing/) by [nikzzzlegrande](https://answers.ros.org/users/50186/nikzzzlegrande/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok I found out solution and fixed it. while making the catkin workspace
mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
catkin_init_workspace

use the above command to initialize the workspace and then you can just continue with

cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make

---

Originally posted by [nikzzzlegrande](https://answers.ros.org/users/50186/nikzzzlegrande/) with karma: 16 on 2019-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0